# How to slide in 50% Activity?

Tags: android, android-transitions

This is my slide in anim

It can slide in MyActivity and stop at 50%

But, when the animation is finish, the activity will become 100% of screen, how can I keep it 50%?

Update 1:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in,R.anim.out);
```

in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="50%p"
        />
</set>
```

out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        />
</set>
```

Comment: add `android:fromXDelta="50%p"  android:toXDelta="0%p"`

Comment: http://madcoda.com/2013/09/android-activity-transition-slide-in-out-animation/

Comment: My X is correct, because I just want to slide activity from bottom, I also tried to add `android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"`, but the activity still display as 100%

Comment: i mean you need to add `overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in,
                android.R.anim.#IN_HERE);`

Comment: I updated my question, since I want the first activity display in background, so X should be `android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"`, and then I added this anim to second parameter, but the result still same.

Comment: @CLSo why do you want to stop activity at 50%?

Comment: because many apps have similar design http://vizteck.com/wp-content/uploads/navigation-drawer1.jpg

Comment: omg :d I'll post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [Navigation Drawer](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android) and not activity stuck in the middle of the screen.

To position drawer on different side change `android:layout_gravity` property. 
`android:layout_gravity="start"` is for left to right.
`android:layout_gravity="end" is for right to left.

**Edit**

It seems you need [SlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). Take a look.
From Docs:

> You can set an anchor point in the middle of the screen using setAnchorPoint to allow an intermediate expanded state for the panel (similar to Google Maps).

Comment: I just use Navigation Drawer as example, but that is not what I want, because it cannot slide from bottom, and I also need the second activity has transparent background, user can see first activity when second activity over it, so I implement by self.

Comment: no, you are wrong. then you need a different component for that.
check updated answer